# A biased coin has probability p of landing heads.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

The coin tossing is repeated independently until n tails have been seen. Find
the moment generating function of the total number of heads.

I know the number of tosses before the first head is p(X=x)=(1-p)p^x x=0,1,2,...

I know that the moment generating function is found by E(e^tx)

I'm not quite sure how to apply this information and if there is any other information I should know before attempting to answer the question?

Comment: It would help if you detailed the steps you have taken to solve it and where exactly you got stuck. SE is not a place where you post a textbook excercise and somebody else works it out for you :)

Comment: It is good that you already showed some things you know in your edit. Maybe you can say in your question in some way or another this is the information I know, but that you don't see how to put this information together. Also you can ask whether you maybe still miss some information, if you are unsure about having all theorems/lemmas/formulas and definitions.

Comment: If you can find the moment-generating function $M_k(t)$ for the number of heads until $k = 1$ tail is seen, then you can take advantage of the relation that $M_k(t) = [M_1(t)]^k$.